# Scan operator with a result selector

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, reactive-streams, rx.net

In Rx.NET, `Aggregate` has an overload that accepts a `resultSelector`, but `Scan` does not. Is there a reason for this? And how would I go about creating a `Scan` operator that does accept a result selector, i.e., with signature: `IObservable<TResult> Scan<TSource,TAccumulate,TResult>(this IObservable<TSource> source, TAccumulate seed, Func<TAccumulate,TSource,TAccumulate> accumulator, Func<TAccumulate,TResult> resultSelector)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the trivial implementation below sufficient?

```
public static IObservable<TResult> Scan<TSource, TAccumulate, TResult>(
    this IObservable<TSource> source,
    TAccumulate seed,
    Func<TAccumulate, TSource, TAccumulate> accumulator,
    Func<TAccumulate, TResult> resultSelector)
{
    return source.Scan(seed, accumulator).Select(resultSelector);
}
```

Comment: Thanks - yes I think this is ok. On a side note, the type of my accumulate is actually a queue, and in the result selector I'd like to dequeue elements from the queue. Is this considered bad practice?

Comment: @jackdry IMHO writing "side-effecting" Rx code is OK. Obviously by doing so the code becomes more fragile and difficult to maintain, but sometimes you have to do it, because the alternatives are just worse. My suggestion though would be to make your intentions explicit by using an operator intended specifically for introducing side-effects, namely the `Do` operator, instead of hiding the side-effects inside seemingly innocuous `Select` projections.